# If a string is rotation of other. All test cases Not running

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am using the logic of concatenation the 2nd string and then searching first string in it.
But for some reason, the code does not run for all test cases.

**example**

```
s1 = rahul , s2 = hulra

s2.s2 = hulrahulra
```

and then search `s1` in `s2.s2` using `strstr()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int ifRotation(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    int l1 = strlen(s1);
    int l2 = strlen(s2);

    char str1[l1], str2[l2+ l2];

    int i;
    i = 0;

    while(*s1 != '\0')
    {
        str1[i] = *s1;
        i++;
        s1++;   
    }
    i = 0;
    while(*s2 != '\0')
    {
        str2[i] = *s2;
        i++;
        s2++;   
    }

    strcat(s2, s2);

    if(strstr(s2, s1))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    //code

    int queries;

    scanf("%d", &queries);
    int array[queries];
    char str1[100];
    char str2[100];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < queries)
    {
        scanf("%s", &str1);
        scanf("%s", &str2);
        array[i] = ifRotation(str1, str2);
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while(i < queries)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: For such small programs you should start using a debugger to see where it fails.

Comment: the *described* logic looks fine to me. The code is at least overcomplicated, have a look at the `strcpy()` function. And then: give a testcase that actually fails!

Comment: Isn't your compiler giving you warnings? It should.

Comment: You shall not forget to allocate memory for terminating `'\0'` byte of strings!

Comment: obvious bug: `strcat(s2, s2);` -> `strcat(str2, s2);`. .. and `strstr()` should be called on your **local** strings. And yes, room for the terminator is missing in your local strings.

Comment: Why do you copy in a `while` loop instead of using `strcpy`? Or why do you copy `s1` at all?

Comment: well, what the program is **trying** to do: https://ideone.com/q0SFEM

Comment: how about including a stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

You are just copying from one string to another, and the copy routine has several problems.

1. `char str1[l1]` is not large enough. It should be `char str1[l1 + 1]`. The extra 1 is for the null character.
2. The string should always end  with null character `'\0'`.
3. `s1` and `s2` are incremented until they reach the null character, so by that time `s1` and `s2` are empty.

Try the following code for copying the strings, you will see `s1/s2` will be empty, `str1/str2` are just copies of the original `s1/s2`.

You can fix the copying as follows:

```
char str1[l1 + 1], str2[l2 + 1];

int i;
i = 0;
while(*s1 != '\0')
{
    str1[i] = *s1;
    i++;
    s1++;
}
str1[i] = '\0';

i = 0;
while(*s2 != '\0')
{
    str2[i] = *s2;
    i++;
    s2++;
}
str2[i] = '\0';

printf("s1=%s, s2=%s, str1=%s, str2=%s\n", s1, s2, str1, str2);
//output: s1=, s2=, str1=old_s1, str2=old_s2
```

But this doesn't really achieve anything. If you just want to check `"rahul"` is the reverse of `"hulra"`, keep `s1` as it is, copy `s2` to `reverse_s2` in reverse order, and compare the two strings as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int ifRotation(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    if(!s1 || !s2)
        return 0;

    int len2 = strlen(s2);
    char reverse_s2[len2 + 1];

    //copy s2 to reverse_s2 in reverse order:
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < len2; i++)
        reverse_s2[i] = s2[len2 - i - 1];
    reverse_s2[i] = '\0'; //add null character

    int result = strcmp(s1, reverse_s2) == 0;

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf("%d\n", ifRotation("rahul", "hulra"));
    printf("%d\n", ifRotation("rahul", "luhar"));
    return 0;
}
```